# Is there a name for a design technique where an object's method takes input and returns custom business object?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, php, patterns-and-practices

What do you call a class that has methods that

- take input (from user, from GET or POST)
- transform it to a business object and return that object

example ...

```
class Input
{
    function getObject(array $input)
    {
        $o = new Object();
        $o->setVars($input);
        return $o;
    }
}

$o = (new Input())->getObject($_POST);
```

Comment: It looks more or less like a *Factory Method* to me, though it's probably just a *method.*

Comment: [Hopefully an input sanitizing method](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: it is .. it uses `filter_var`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RobertHarvey commented a **Factory Method** might be an appropriate name.  When it comes to web applications **Model Binding** is another good term I've seen in reference to mapping data in an HTTP request to some sort of concrete object.

> Model binding in ASP.NET Core MVC maps data from HTTP requests to action method parameters. The parameters may be simple types such as strings, integers, or floats, or they may be complex types.

Source: [Introduction to model binding](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/models/model-binding.html)

A **Data Mapper** is also a good name.

Whichever one you choose will largely depend on context. If we are talking about parameters in an HTTP request go with Model Binder. If talking about taking data from one type and converting it to another then a Data Mapper fits. Lastly if it is a general purpose method that decides at runtime which concrete type to create based on input then you have a Factory Method/Object.